# updating a formula - how do I "cancel" a function: log(y) --> y?

Tags: r

I don't want use the arithmetic inverse because something could be lost. For example, if there are negative values, log will give `NA`s. Is there a "formula inverse"? I've looked at `?formula`, `?update.formula`, and `?terms.formula`. I thought that `terms.formula` might have something that could help me, but I don't think so.

In the following, I would like a `cancel` function, like in `temp2`. I would like it to give the same result as `temp3`.

```
temp1 <- log(y) ~ x
temp2 <- update(temp1, cancel(.) ~ .)
temp3 <- update(temp1, y ~ .)
```

I am not only interested in `log`. Here is another example:

```
foo1 <- factor(y) ~ x
foo2 <- update(foo1, y ~ .) #I would like this same result, but without having to use "y"
```

I would like something simple. I've tried something like

```
temp1[2] <- gsub("log","",temp1[2])
```

And I could not get it to work. But I do not know if I would want this anyway.

Any ideas?

[edit: more context]
I am really interested in this for readability purposes. I love the `update.formula` function because I think it makes code really readable. Instead of having to compare two formulas to figure out what the differences are, update.formula shows that directly. Thus, I have a model that I'm currently working with that has the dependent variable as `factor(y)`. I would like to update that formula to just `y`. I could just do it explicitly, but just as you can go from `y` to `factor(y)` by using `factor(.)`, I would like to tell the reader that I am updating the formula by doing the same, something like `take_off_factor(.)`. For example, if I define my model at the beginning, and then in the middle of the code I have `new_model <- update(original_model, y ~ .)`, you have to go back and find the original model to figure out what my dependent variable was before. It could have been `log(y)` or `factor(y)`. By doing something like `take_off_factor(.)` ~ . you know that the old model had `factor(y)`. Sure, I could just add comments to explain what I'm doing. I will do that, but I also think that good code should speak for itself.

Comment: As is often the case, I think a little bit more context about what you're trying to do would be helpful

Comment: @BenBolker Sure, I can provide some more context. I will edit my original post.

Comment: This is not unreasonable but it seems to me that a robust general solution would be quite difficult.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for the response and edits. Well, at least now I know that there is no easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double square bracket subsetting (`[[`) to extract components of a formula and its constituent calls, eg,

```
temp1[[2]]
log(y)
temp1[[2]][[2]]
y
```

Therefore for this example (removing the outermost function) using it twice is enough. To combine it together you need to use paste to evaluate and then convert back to a formula:

```
temp2 <- update(temp1,formula(paste(temp1[[2]][[2]],"~.")))
temp2
y ~ x
```

Or, you could change the formula directly:

```
temp3 <- temp1
temp3[[2]] <- temp1[[2]][[2]]
temp3
y~x
```

Comment: Thanks James, I think that this is the best that can be done. How do I find out why `[[` can do that? `methods("[[")` doesn't give anything for class "call", which is what `temp1[[2]]` is, and `?"[[.call"` does not give anything.

Comment: @XuWang I think `[[` coerces it to a list first, try `as.list(temp1)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. For reference, I think you mean `as.list(temp1[[2]])`. Any idea on how to know that `[[` coerces it to a list? Not important, just curious.

Comment: It does the same to the "formula" and the "call". I stumbled on it by trial and error. `[[` is a primitive, so it will be in the R source code, or http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html may shed some light

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult, because if the function is not [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), then inverting it may mean getting multiple values (i.e. multiple possible inputs may result in the same possible output). In those cases, you may have to resolve the solutions numerically, which would frequently take a long, long time.

You can define a class or function that allows log to take negative values (remembering the input and the absolute value of the input); then this can be inverted. Effectively, you'd be using complex numbers without directly doing so.

Another option is to store pairs of inputs and outputs fed into and out of the function; then you can simply look up the correct input in the pair.